# How can I ask for location and display it on map on my website?

Tags: javascript, maps, geolocation

I have added a map to my website. Now I want to add a feature to it wherein when a user clicks on the add event button on the header a popup should appear which ask for event name and location and as soon as the user submits the information the location gets marked on the map with a style icon.

[image]

[image]

(I have added the code to show the popup with the relevant input form but I am not able to link the location with the map with a style icon containing the information).

Comment: That's a damn cool map, where did you get it?